# Regression analysis with special cost function

Tags: regression, modeling, loss-functions, measurement-error

I want to do regression analysis using a special cost function that penalizes the *sign* error more than the square of the error.

For example, I have a number of monthly change observations that can have negative values. $Y$ is +1100 January, +500 February, -100 March. If my predictor $X$ has values 100 January, -500 February, -100 March the least square cost function will calculate the same error for the first two values ($1000^2$), although for my problem the second error is worse: I want to penalize more the direction error than the distance.

I am not looking for logistic regression because the issue here is not to simply predict a binary outcome, but rather combine the binary error with the squared error. What kind of regression analysis should I look into?

Comment: How about some kind of iteratively reweighted least-squares regression, in which you put increasing weights on the observations whose fitted values have incorrect sign?  Look up "boosting".